Solana.py Transfer error not working
Please how do i so solana transfer, the codes seems to be emitting an issue from solana's own api file.
def Sol_Transfer(user_number, recipient: str, amount: float):
private_key = get_private_key(user_number)
private_key_bytes = bytes.fromhex(private_key)
# Ensure the private key bytes are 32 bytes long
if len(private_key_bytes) != 32:
    raise ValueError("Private key must be 32 bytes long")
# Create a Keypair from the 32-byte private key
sender_keypair = Keypair.from_seed(private_key_bytes)
# Correctly derive the public key from the Keypair
sender_pubkey = sender_keypair.pubkey()
# Create a Message instance
message = Message(
    # account_keys=[sender_pubkey, PublicKey.from_string(recipient)],
    instructions=[transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey=sender_pubkey, to_pubkey=PublicKey.from_string(recipient), lamports=amount * 1_000_000))],
)
# Get a recent blockhash
solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
# Get the latest blockhash
latest_blockhash_resp = solana_client.get_latest_blockhash()
recent_blockha = getattr(latest_blockhash_resp.value, 'blockhash', None)
# Assuming recent_blockhash is already obtained as shown in your code
# Create a Transaction instance
txn = Transaction([sender_keypair],message,recent_blockha)
# Sign the transaction with the recent_blockhash
txn.sign([sender_keypair], recent_blockha)
# Send the transaction
return solana_client.send_transaction(txn)

it throw this error
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/workspaces/Web3-Wallet/transfer.py", line 118, in Sol_Transfer(1, 'EccxYg7rViwYfn9EMoNu7sUaV82QGyFt6ewiQaH1GYjv', 9) File "/workspaces/Web3-Wallet/transfer.py", line 114, in Sol_Transfer return solana_client.send_transaction(txn) File "/home/codespace/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/solana/rpc/api.py", line 1048, in send_transaction txn.recent_blockhash = recent_blockhash AttributeError: 'solders.transaction.Transaction' object has no attribute 'recent_blockhash'

This is a very strange error... I wonder if you're using incompatible versions of solana-py and solders. Can you be sure to use the newest version of both?
